# What's a good Prolog IDE for Linux?

Tags: linux, ide, prolog

I need to write some Prolog programs for a class.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Prolog mode for (X)Emacs.

See http://bruda.ca/emacs-prolog/

Comment: (X)Emacs will probably be worth getting familiar with. (If you're not already)

Comment: Emacs is the best option. X-Emacs is dead AFAIC.

Answer (score 16):

As mentioned you can use SWI-Prolog. If you like Eclipse there is an Eclipse plug-in that integrates SWI-Prolog into Eclipse. This way you have the best of both worlds, for example the SVN etc functions of Eclipse and the graphic debugger of SWI-Prolog. Worth checking out.

http://sewiki.iai.uni-bonn.de/research/pdt/start

Comment: @user2278330 - Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have a question, please [open a new thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), rather than modifying an existing answer. You can include a link to this response if its relevant.

Answer (score 14):

[SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/IDE.html) comes with excellent IDE tools, an Emacs-clone text editor, interactive debugger, complete browseable help system and docs. Give it a try.

Answer (score 7):

I've not tried it (mostly because I never thought to combine the words "Prolog" and "NetBeans" before now), but there appears to be [Prolog support for NetBeans](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/60/nbm-prolog.html).  It's not a simple plugin, but a tutorial that shows how to add Prolog support to NetBeans.

Comment: I'd say NetBeans was _way_ overkill for Prolog.  I find any old text editor (gedit does okay, but I use a Mac with SubEthaEdit).  If you can change a mode so that comments are marked, there isn't really much syntax to highlight!

Comment: If you were already using NetBeans for Java, C++, or Ruby, though, you'd be familiar with it and want to use it for Prolog too.

Comment: NB ide doesn't support Prolog. What you refer to is how to create an IDE that supports Prolog based on NB Platform.

Comment: @simpatico: Thanks, I updated my answer to try and make it more clear that the link goes to a tutorial, not a plugin.

Answer (score 7):

A good point to start is to use Emacs' default Prolog mode plus the additions described [here](http://www.metalevel.at/pceprolog/pceprolog.html). You can also try [ediprolog](http://www.metalevel.at/ediprolog/ediprolog.html), which aims for a tighter Emacs-Prolog integration.

Answer (score 6):

[Ideone](http://ideone.com) supports Prolog. You can use it online just with a browser.

Answer (score 5):

Prolog Development Tools (ProDT) is a Prolog Integrated Development Environment (IDE) aiming to be as rich in functionality as the Eclipse's java IDE, giving the developer a single environment where it can control the development of a Prolog project from code edition, test execution, etc...

This project stands on top of Eclipse's projects to take advantage of its already existent features and its extensibility and works on any environment Eclipse works including windows, linux and mac OSX.

It support as underlying interpreters: SWI-prolog, XSB prolog, B-prolog

The site has more information about the project including installation and features list: http://prodevtools.sourceforge.net/

Hope you can find it useful!!! :)

Comment: Fantastic recommendation, and it worked for me (MacBook Pro) right out of the box.  I had a lot of trouble with Swi-Prolog's built-in one.

Answer (score 5):

[SPIDER](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/spider/site/index.html) is a Eclipse-based IDE for [SICStus Prolog](http://www.sics.se/isl/sicstuswww/site/index.html). SICStus Prolog also has a very useful Emacs mode.

Answer (score 3):

If you are used to an Emacs environment I would recommend the Ciao distribution. Go to: http://ciaohome.org/

Answer (score 3):

swi prolog and emacs extension is preinstalled in almost every linux distribution.
You can check this using e.g., the commands below in and X11-enabled (graphical) environment. This should open a new window with the built-in Emacs clone.

```
% swipl
?- emacs.
```

http://www.swi-prolog.org/build/LinuxDistro.txt

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Prolog](http://www.visual-prolog.com/) (works with Wine).

Answer (score 1):

I just use Vim or jEdit.  Prolog as a language doesn't really lend itself to strong IDE support.  For one thing, it's dynamically typed, which throws a huge wrench into tooling.  For another, it's a logic-based language, which means that the "code flow" (order in which you construct the program) is non-linear.  Existing techniques for building highly advanced IDEs just don't apply to that sort of paradigm.

Comment: I don't agree. Prolog is a fundamentally different language that say OO, but that doesn't mean that it doesn't lend itself to strong IDE support. One problem with many languages which cause trouble when doing an IDE is that the existing language implementations do not expose a powerful enough API to access things like the AST and program semantics. Eclipse has a Java compiler explicitly designed to interact with an IDE which makes it much easier to do things like advanced refactoring.

Comment: Daniel, you may want to check e.g. PDT, available at https://sewiki.iai.uni-bonn.de/research/pdt/start

Answer (score 1):

You could use Gprolog, we use that in our class. Use consult('filename') to load the database.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I can't see an 'IDE' helping out much on prolog. It'll only aid in finding syntax errors. The rest is in the debugging and the thought process.

Get syntax-highlighting with any editor and you're set to go.